# How to Fix Weird C++ Codes that Assume the Relative Ordering of Class Members

Tags: c++, refactoring, case-tools

I need to modify the ordering of my C++ class members. For example:

```
class B {
public:
int i;
int j;
int k;
...
};
```

becomes

```
class B {
public:
int j;
int k;
int i;
...
};
```

The problem is there are weird codes in my large code bases that depend on relative location of the class members.  For example some functions would assume address of member j is smaller than that of member k.

Is there any CASE tool that can help me to identify any code that read the address of a class member?

Comment: Seems like an XY question. What are you ACTUALLY trying to achieve?

Comment: Some clever guys (who have left) wrote some codes that assume the relative ordering of the class members.  I need to figure out where those codes are and fix them using the smallest amount of time

Comment: How many classes do you have, and will re-ordering the objects show the problem immediately?

Comment: Hundreds of classes.  There is no compile time error and we need to run a lot of tests to see the error.

Comment: Why do you need to change the ordering?

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording.  I just need to make sure someone who maintain the code in the future can assume the ordering is irrelevant.  I don't really need to change the ordering.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any tool that solve your problem, but I would define a class which supports all operators for `int` type and which overloads ampersand operator so that the result of the operator cannot be casted to a pointer. Then I'd use this class instead of `int` in your class member definitions and look at places where compiler gives errors.

Something like

```
class IntWrapper {
 public:
  IntWrapper() { }
  IntWrapper(const int x) { }         // don't care about implementation as we 
  operator int() const { return 0; }  // want compile-time errors only
  IntWrapper& operator ++() { return *this; }
  IntWrapper& operator ++(int) { return *this; }

  ...
  void operator &() const { } // make it void so it would cause compiler error
};
```

And then:

```
class B {
 public:
  IntWrapper i;
  IntWrapper j;
  IntWrapper k;
 ...
};
```

This will not help against using `boost::addressof` function or some dirty `reinterpret_cast` of a reference, but `addressof` is probably never used at all in your project, as well as the `reinterpret_cast<char&>` trick (who would use it for plain integers?).

You should also care about taking an address of the whole object of `B` class.

Comment: my source codes use a lot of c++ standard offsetof() macro which is just implemented as reinterpret_cast<volatile char&> in VC++. Are there any other possible ways to get the offset of a member?

Comment: It's possible to redefine `offsetof(s,m)` as `(size_t)&( ((s*)0) -> m)`, so it uses operator `&` for the source type. But it could be easier just to search for `offsetof(class B,` through the whole project.

Comment: Sorry, I meant searching for `offsetof(B,`.

Comment: To find `offsetof` issues, change to `Intwrapper` and compile with GCC. It warns you about attempts to use `offsetof` on UDTs.